# Javascript POST will not load in PHP page

Tags: php, javascript, post

I have a javascript function to manipulate some form data and build POST to a php page. The js does an xmlHTTP.open and send to the url that is built.

The php page should accept the parameters and send off an email, but it doesn't seem to accept the parameters.

I know there is something stupid I'm missing here, but my I have other pages that are similar, but with less parameters and they work fine.

```
<script>
function submitReg()
{
    var fn = document.getElementById("textfname").value;
    var ln = document.getElementById("textlname").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("textemail").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("textphone").value;
    var pr = document.getElementById("promocode").value;
    var c1 = document.getElementById("st-1").innerHTML + "_" 
    + document.getElementById("c-  1").innerHTML;
    if (document.getElementById("st-2").innerHTML != "")
    {
        var c2 = document.getElementById("st-2").innerHTML + "_" + 
    document.getElementById("c-2").innerHTML;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("st-3").innerHTML != "")
    {
        var c3 = document.getElementById("st-3").innerHTML + "_" + 
    document.getElementById("c-3").innerHTML;
    }
    var myURL = "form-to-email.php?" + "fn=" + fn + "&ln=" + ln + "&e=" + e + 
    "&p=" + p + "&pr=" + pr + "&c1=" + c1 + "&c2=" + c2 + "&c3=" + c3;


    xmlhttp.open("POST", (encodeURI(myURL)), true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

And the PHP code:

```
<?php

$fname = $_POST["fn"];
$lname = $_POST["ln"];
$email = $_POST["e"];
$phone = $_POST["p"];
$promo = $_POST["pr"];
$county1 = $_POST["c1"];
$county2 = $_POST["c2"];
$county3 = $_POST["c3"];



$email_from = 'support@somesite.com';

$email_subject = "Someone filled out the Splash page";

$email_body = "You have received a new form submission from the user $visitor_email.\n".
                        "Here it is:\n ".
            "First Name: $fname \n".
"Last Name: $lname \n".
"Email: $email \n".
"Phone: $phone \n".
"Promo Code: $promo \n".
"First County: $county1 \n".
"Second County(if Any): $county2 \n".
"Third County(if Any): $county3 \n";

$to = "user@gmail.com";

$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
Header("Location: thankyou.html");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sending an empty POST with a lot of GET parameters set, and your php code is expecting POST parameters.

Either use the post properly:

```
var myURL = "form-to-email.php";
var params = "fn=" + encodeURIComponent(fn) + "&ln=" + encodeURIComponent(ln) + "&e=" + encodeURIComponent(e) + "&p=" + encodeURIComponent(p) + "&pr=" + encodeURIComponent(pr) + "&c1=" + encodeURIComponent(c1) + "&c2=" + encodeURIComponent(c2) + "&c3=" + encodeURIComponent(c3);
xmlhttp.open("POST", myURL, true);
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Or prepare PHP to receive "GET" parameters:

```
$fname = $_GET["fn"];
```

Or don't worry from php side if they are GET or POST params:

```
$fname = $_REQUEST["fn"];
```

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up the 500 error I was getting, but I'm still receiving emails without any of the values passed. Just the template of the page, and thankyou.html just blinks by,